# How to select one value in a df according to three conditions for three different variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like next:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Delay=rep(-5:5, times=4, each=1),
                 ID= rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times=1, each=11),
                 variable=rep(c("R2","SE"), times=11, each=1),
                 value=sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 44, replace=TRUE))

df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df$variable <- as.factor(df$variable)

head(df)
  Delay ID variable value
1    -5  A       R2  0.30
2    -4  A       SE  0.78
3    -3  A       R2  0.50
4    -2  A       SE  0.13
5    -1  A       R2  0.66
6     0  A       SE  0.41
```

I want to get the `Delay` value for which `ID=="B"`, `variable=="R2"` and `value` has the minimum value.

How could I find this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is agnostic to the version of R, but the results are sensitive (here) to the randomness (apparently changed somewhere between R-3.5.3 and R-4.0.0).

### R-3.5.3

```r
with(df[order(df$value),], Delay[ID == "B" & variable == "R2"])
# [1] -2  0  2 -4  4
with(df[order(df$value),], Delay[ID == "B" & variable == "R2"][1])
# [1] -2

dput(df)
# structure(list(Delay = c(-5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("R2", "SE")), value = c(0.29, 0.79, 0.41, 0.89, 0.94, 0.04, 0.53, 0.9, 0.55, 0.46, 0.96, 0.45, 0.68, 0.57, 0.1, 0.9, 0.24, 0.04, 0.33, 0.96, 0.89, 0.69, 0.64, 1, 0.66, 0.71, 0.54, 0.6, 0.29, 0.14, 0.97, 0.91, 0.69, 0.8, 0.02, 0.48, 0.76, 0.21, 0.32, 0.23, 0.14, 0.41, 0.41, 0.37)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```

### R-4.0.0

```r
with(df[order(df$value),], Delay[ID == "B" & variable == "R2"])
# [1]  4 -4 -2  0  2
with(df[order(df$value),], Delay[ID == "B" & variable == "R2"][1])
# [1] 4

dput(df)
# structure(list(Delay = c(-5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("R2", "SE"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.3, 0.78, 0.5, 0.13, 0.66, 0.41, 0.49, 0.42, 1, 0.13, 0.24, 0.89, 0.9, 0.68, 0.9, 0.56, 0.91, 0.08, 0.92, 0.98, 0.71, 0.25, 0.06, 0.41, 0.08, 0.82, 0.35, 0.77, 0.8, 0.42, 0.75, 0.14, 0.31, 0.06, 0.08, 0.4, 0.73, 0.22, 0.26, 0.59, 0.52, 0.06, 0.52, 0.26)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Where they differ

The "randomness" of the data is sensitive to the R version.

If you're curious, the left three (non-random) columns are identical, it's only the `value` column that varies. Combining the two `df`s (and naming for R-version) presents

```r
df
#    Delay ID variable R-3.5.3 R-4.0.0
# 1     -5  A       R2    0.29    0.30
# 2     -4  A       SE    0.79    0.78
# 3     -3  A       R2    0.41    0.50
# 4     -2  A       SE    0.89    0.13
# 5     -1  A       R2    0.94    0.66
# 6      0  A       SE    0.04    0.41
# 7      1  A       R2    0.53    0.49
# 8      2  A       SE    0.90    0.42
# 9      3  A       R2    0.55    1.00
# 10     4  A       SE    0.46    0.13
# 11     5  A       R2    0.96    0.24
# 12    -5  B       SE    0.45    0.89
# 13    -4  B       R2    0.68    0.90
# 14    -3  B       SE    0.57    0.68
# 15    -2  B       R2    0.10    0.90
# 16    -1  B       SE    0.90    0.56
# 17     0  B       R2    0.24    0.91
# 18     1  B       SE    0.04    0.08
# 19     2  B       R2    0.33    0.92
# 20     3  B       SE    0.96    0.98
# 21     4  B       R2    0.89    0.71
# 22     5  B       SE    0.69    0.25
# 23    -5  C       R2    0.64    0.06
# 24    -4  C       SE    1.00    0.41
# 25    -3  C       R2    0.66    0.08
# 26    -2  C       SE    0.71    0.82
# 27    -1  C       R2    0.54    0.35
# 28     0  C       SE    0.60    0.77
# 29     1  C       R2    0.29    0.80
# 30     2  C       SE    0.14    0.42
# 31     3  C       R2    0.97    0.75
# 32     4  C       SE    0.91    0.14
# 33     5  C       R2    0.69    0.31
# 34    -5  D       SE    0.80    0.06
# 35    -4  D       R2    0.02    0.08
# 36    -3  D       SE    0.48    0.40
# 37    -2  D       R2    0.76    0.73
# 38    -1  D       SE    0.21    0.22
# 39     0  D       R2    0.32    0.26
# 40     1  D       SE    0.23    0.59
# 41     2  D       R2    0.14    0.52
# 42     3  D       SE    0.41    0.06
# 43     4  D       R2    0.41    0.52
# 44     5  D       SE    0.37    0.26
```

### Why they differ

As @KonradRudolph suggested, this changed in R_3.6, where (I am just reading this):

```
    * The default method for generating from a discrete uniform
      distribution (used in sample(), for instance) has been changed.
      This addresses the fact, pointed out by Ottoboni and Stark, that
      the previous method made sample() noticeably non-uniform on large
      populations.  See PR#17494 for a discussion.  The previous method
      can be requested using RNGkind() or RNGversion() if necessary for
      reproduction of old results.  Thanks to Duncan Murdoch for
      contributing the patch and Gabe Becker for further assistance.

      The output of RNGkind() has been changed to also return the
      'kind' used by sample().
```

(Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000641.html and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.3.html)

Comment: Your code produces the correct result but the results included in your answer in the comment is the wrong way round. (Not my downvote, btw).

Comment: I don't understand "wrong way round". Is it because I sort by value before subsetting? @KonradRudolph

Comment: When I copy OP’s DF creation code into R 4.0.0 and execute your code, I get `[1]  4 -4 -2  0  2`, and the result is therefore 4, not -2.

Comment: That is solely a R-4.0 versus (my) R-3.5.3 thing. When I type my code into R-4.0, I get `# [1]  4 -4 -2  0  2`. Interesting that the two R versions are different.

Comment: Indeed, I now tried it with R 3.5 and R 3.6 and get the same as you for 3.5. How bizarre, and slightly scary.  I knew R had changed the way the RNG works in R 3.6 but it’s a huge coincidence that this would result in an exact reversal of the order of the result.

Comment: It's not a "reversal" per se, it's just ... different random data. I had *not* heard about the RNG change, +1 your "scare" comment, that breaks backward-compatible reproducibility in some fields/functions.

Comment: Yeah, R has the lovely peculiarity of having regular (!) breaking changes in minor version number updates. This particular one, while serious, is at least understandable because the old RNG had a serious bug that resulted in randomness deficiencies. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.3.html

Comment: (I see the initial impetus to downvote given that perspective, now informed by this *nuance* ... \*shrug\*. Thanks @KonradRudolph.)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer first orders the data and then subsets it. Here’s an approach that does the opposite: first subsetting and then finding the minimum. On large data, this is potentially substantially faster:

```
subset = df[df$ID == 'B' & df$variable == 'R2', ]
subset$Delay[which.min(subset$value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, I will recommend you to use

```
with(subset(df,ID=="B"&variable=="R2"),Delay[which.min(value)])
[1] 4
```

Answer (score -1):

with tidyverse you can do

```r
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(ID == 'B'  & variable == "R2") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(value == min(value)) %>% 
  `[[`(1)
```

Comment: OP specifically requested a base R solution.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I can not find anything that says he wants a base R solution

Comment: It’s tagged [tag:base-r].

Comment: I did not know that tags must be understood as a requirement. Now I do.

Answer (score -1):

A solution using `tidyverse`, which I always find easier to interpret that base R:

```
library(tidyverse)

(df %>% filter(ID=="B", variable=="R2") %>% slice_min(value))$Delay
```

Giving

```
[1] -2
```

Comment: OP specifically requested a base R solution.